# Use pixmap data instead of url for Qt stylesheet image property

Tags: qt, pyside2

Because I'm loading my icons from a font, I cannot provide a url for a `image` property in stylesheets. I only have access to the `QPixmap` or `QIcon`. However I'm not sure what other kind of data the `image` property accepts besides url's. This is what I tried:

```py
arrow_up_icon = FontIcon('arrow-up', color='white')
arrow_up_pixmap = arrow_up_icon.pixmap(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))

header = QtWigets.QHeaderView()
header.setStyleSheet("""
    QHeaderView::up-arrow{
        image: %s;
    }
""" % arrow_up_pixmap)
```

Comment: You could save those images to the temp folder on startup, and then set their path dynamically in the stylesheet.

Comment: A data-url might have been a solution, but apparently it's not (yet) supported: [QTBUG-51081](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51081).