# How to add picture containing transparency to the window background using code?

Tags: c++, qt

How to set a png file containing transparency to the window background

using only code and **not** css/stylesheet?

With the following code the picture is added however, the background became black in the parts where
the image is not painted

```
ui.setupUi(this);

QPixmap bkgnd(":/pic");
//bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);

//bkgnd.fill(Qt::transparent);

QPalette palette;
//palette.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::transparent);
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Window, bkgnd);

this->setPalette(palette);
//this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
```

Commented are things i already tried.

Comment: Note that there's only a degree of difference between setting color by `"#4629b1"`, and setting color by using style sheet embedded in code, contain that color. What I mean is, "I don't want to use style sheets because it is not code" is a bit misguided. If you don't want to deal with strings in your actual widgets, create a helper class, which has all the properties you want, and a method like `void MyStyleHandler::stylizeWidget(QWidget *target)`, so you don't ever need to touch style sheets outside that one helper class.

Comment: What you want to do _may_ not be possible without style sheets. Not sure so not writing an answer. But there are a number of things in styles which are so complex, that they really need the CSS DSL to describe them, it'd be crazy to try to have "pure" or "direct" C++ to do it. For some basic styling, you have these methods, but CSS (or QSS, not 100% identical to HTML CSS) is what you have to use to describe any serious styling. So for this background&transparency thing, it's quite plausible, even likely, that nobody ever made a "direct" C++ interface for it.

Comment: @hyde i see, how would it be coding the stylesheet ?

Comment: Well, it's a string... just construct the style sheet string by code. You need to learn the style sheet DSL then, of course, unless you just want to use snippets found from net to do what you want... https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html (also, if you want to use a runtime-generated QImage, unfortunately [you have to save it in a temp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690657/use-pixmap-data-instead-of-url-for-qt-stylesheet-image-property), it seems).